# Primary Key Violation in spring batch's BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE TABLE while running job parallel

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch admin 3.0.3 with spring 3.2.0.Release with SQL Server 2008. I am getting following exception when I try to run multiple jobs simultaneously.
The stack trace is as follow.

```
[ERROR] 2015-04-07 18:50:40.991 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#3_Worker-1] BatchJobScheduler executeInternal -
                    Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154A7F60ED59'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (0).
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154A7F60ED59'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (0).
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:824) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:818) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:818) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:874) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:878) ~[spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:115) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:135) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260) ~[spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) ~[spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.abc.testme.batchjobs.util.BatchJobUtils.runJob(BatchJobUtils.java:154) ~[BatchJobUtils.class:?]
    at com.abc.testme.batchjobs.util.BatchJobUtils.runJobWithCheckForRunningExecutions(BatchJobUtils.java:136) ~[BatchJobUtils.class:?]
    at com.abc.testme.batchjobs.util.BatchJobUtils.runJob(BatchJobUtils.java:80) ~[BatchJobUtils.class:?]
    at com.abc.testme.batchjobs.scheduler.BatchJobScheduler.executeInternal(BatchJobScheduler.java:52) [BatchJobScheduler.class:?]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:113) [spring-context-support-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216) [quartz-1.8.5.jar:?]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549) [quartz-1.8.5.jar:?]
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154A7F60ED59'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (0).
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    ... 33 more
```

What I understand is multiple jobs trying to execute update/fetch value from the same table and hence its values are duplicated.Please provide your inputs. However when I run these jobs at an interval of 1minute I don't get any exceptions. Thanks all for reading.

UPDATE : Here is the configuration for transactionManager and datasource

Session Factory:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.abc.testme.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}
                hibernate.show_sql=${hibernate.show_sql}
                hibernate.format.sql=${hibernate.format.sql}
                hibernate.query.substitutions=${hibernate.query.substitutions}
            </value>
            <!-- Turn batching off for better error messages under PostgreSQL -->
            <!-- hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0 -->
        </property>

    </bean>
```

Transaction Manager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
</bean>
```

Datasource:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Can you paste the code which is giving problem?

Comment: the root problem comes from hibernate, under the hood spring batch does NOT use hibernate for persisting the job-metadata, please share your spring xml (or javaconfig) config as well, especially for datasource and transactionmanager

Comment: @MichaelPralow Configuration added.

Comment: ok it tries to insert the same job_instance_id again, actually this should never happen, what can be the cause? i dont know, i would try to debug it, question: why is it trying to insert the same ID twice? i'd start at JobInstanceDao.createJobInstance line 108

Comment: I have debugged the code seems to be issue with SqlServer driver. Also found a bug related to it. Here is the link : https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2147 Not sure though

Comment: @MichaelPralow  Does it seem like a bug to you?

Comment: This is an issue reported here : https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2372 fix version would be 3.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed my configuration to the following adding one more property in the jobRepository that is "isolationLevelForCreate" resolved my issue. Posting it so if anyone faces similar issue this can be helpful.

```
<bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="sqlserver" />
        <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well we faced the same issue and seem to have been able to solve it through configuration.

I still have to investigate if setting `ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ` would have been enough, but while I was at it, I also enabled the DataFieldMaxValueIncrementer-Cache for SQL-Server.

Now 20 ids will be fetched at once and held in a cache, greatly reducing the probability of a deadlock.
If the server stops, up to 20 ids might be "lost", and between the cluster serves the ids will not be strictly increasing - but that's ok for us.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

  private static final String ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ = "ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ";

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;
  @Autowired
  private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

  @Bean
  public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager);
    factory.setValidateTransactionState(true);
    factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate(ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ);
    factory.setIncrementerFactory(customIncrementerFactory());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    return simpleJobLauncher;
  }

  private DataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory customIncrementerFactory() {
    return new CustomDataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory(dataSource);
  }

  private class CustomDataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory extends DefaultDataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory {

    CustomDataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
      super(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public DataFieldMaxValueIncrementer getIncrementer(String incrementerType, String incrementerName) {
      DataFieldMaxValueIncrementer incrementer = super.getIncrementer(incrementerType, incrementerName);
      if (incrementer instanceof SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer) {
        ((SqlServerMaxValueIncrementer) incrementer).setCacheSize(20);
      }
      return incrementer;
    }
  }
}
```

If there's an easier way to achive this, feel free to point me in the direction :)

**UPDATE:**
While the above resolved the errors with "could not increment identity", we were facing other problems now:

> Encountered fatal error executing job org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT STEP_EXECUTION_ID, STEP_NAME, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, COMMIT_COUNT, READ_COUNT, FILTER_COUNT, WRITE_COUNT, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, READ_SKIP_COUNT, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, ROLLBACK_COUNT, LAST_UPDATED, VERSION from BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? order by STEP_EXECUTION_ID]; Die Transaktion (Prozess-ID 477) befand sich auf Sperre | Kommunikationspuffer Ressourcen aufgrund eines anderen Prozesses in einer Deadlocksituation und wurde als Deadlockopfer ausgew?hlt. F?hren Sie die Transaktion erneut aus.; 
>   nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Die Transaktion (Prozess-ID 477) befand sich auf Sperre | Kommunikationspuffer Ressourcen aufgrund eines anderen Prozesses in einer Deadlocksituation und wurde als Deadlockopfer ausgew?hlt. F?hren Sie die Transaktion erneut aus. at 
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:263) at 
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) at 
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649) at 
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684) at 
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716) at 
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726) at 
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:781) at 
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcStepExecutionDao.addStepExecutions(JdbcStepExecutionDao.java:299) at 
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastStepExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:219) at 
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor164.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at 
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ...
>   {noformat}

Different jobs were now trying to insert into the DB at the same time, causing a deadlock. We now set IsolationLevel to "ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED". To prevent executing the same job in parallel on a cluster we've been using Hazelcast-locks all along.

Answer (score 0):

https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2147

So far I've not been able to recreate any issues (deadlocks or duplicate key) using sql server IDENTITY columns instead of psuedo sequences. No need to use retry because deadlocks are no longer occurring. No other solution works in my scenario, I even tried using SQL Server 2012 Sequences. Tested with multiple batch server instances running against a single database. The job used for testing uses partitioning (with ThreadPoolTaskExecutor).

Make the following fields of type IDENTITY:

```
BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE.JOB_INSTANCE_ID
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.JOB_EXECUTION_ID
BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION.STEP_EXECUTION_ID
```

Change or copy JdbcJobInstanceDao (SqlServerJdbcJobInstanceDao) and change the CREATE_JOB_INSTANCE sql constant and createJobInstance method to:

```
private static final String CREATE_JOB_INSTANCE = "INSERT into %PREFIX%JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION)"
        + " values (?, ?, ?)";

@Override
public JobInstance createJobInstance(String jobName,
                                     JobParameters jobParameters) {

    Assert.notNull(jobName, "Job name must not be null.");
    Assert.notNull(jobParameters, "JobParameters must not be null.");

    Assert.state(getJobInstance(jobName, jobParameters) == null, "JobInstance must not already exist");

    JobInstance jobInstance = new JobInstance(null, jobName);
    jobInstance.incrementVersion();

    KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

    getJdbcTemplate().update(connection -> {
        final PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(getQuery(CREATE_JOB_INSTANCE), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setString(1, jobName);
        ps.setString(2, jobKeyGenerator.generateKey(jobParameters));
        ps.setString(3, String.valueOf(jobInstance.getVersion()));
        return ps;
    }, generatedKeyHolder);

    jobInstance.setId(generatedKeyHolder.getKey().longValue());

    return jobInstance;
}
```

Change or copy JdbcJobExecutionDao (SqlServerJdbcJobExecutionDao) and change SAVE_JOB_EXECUTION sql constant and saveJobExecution method:

```
private static final String SAVE_JOB_EXECUTION = "INSERT into %PREFIX%JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, "
        + "END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

@Override
public void saveJobExecution(JobExecution jobExecution) {

    validateJobExecution(jobExecution);

    jobExecution.incrementVersion();

    KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

    getJdbcTemplate().update(connection -> {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(getQuery(SAVE_JOB_EXECUTION), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setLong  ( 1, jobExecution.getJobId());
        ps.setDate  ( 2, jobExecution.getStartTime() != null ? new java.sql.Date(jobExecution.getStartTime().getTime()) : null);
        ps.setDate  ( 3, jobExecution.getEndTime() != null ? new java.sql.Date(jobExecution.getEndTime().getTime()) : null);
        ps.setString( 4, jobExecution.getStatus().toString());
        ps.setString( 5, jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
        ps.setString( 6, jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitDescription());
        ps.setInt   ( 7, jobExecution.getVersion());
        ps.setDate  ( 8, jobExecution.getCreateTime() != null ? new java.sql.Date(jobExecution.getCreateTime().getTime()) : null);
        ps.setDate  ( 9, jobExecution.getLastUpdated() != null ? new java.sql.Date(jobExecution.getLastUpdated().getTime()) : null);
        ps.setString(10, jobExecution.getJobConfigurationName());
        return ps;
    }, generatedKeyHolder);

    jobExecution.setId(generatedKeyHolder.getKey().longValue());

    insertJobParameters(jobExecution.getId(), jobExecution.getJobParameters());
}
```

Change or copy JdbcStepExecutionDao (SqlServerJdbcStepExecutionDao) and change the SAVE_STEP_EXECUTION sql constant and saveStepExecution/saveStepExecutions methods:

```
private static final String SAVE_STEP_EXECUTION = "INSERT into %PREFIX%STEP_EXECUTION(VERSION, STEP_NAME, JOB_EXECUTION_ID, START_TIME, "
        + "END_TIME, STATUS, COMMIT_COUNT, READ_COUNT, FILTER_COUNT, WRITE_COUNT, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, READ_SKIP_COUNT, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, ROLLBACK_COUNT, LAST_UPDATED) "
        + "values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

@Override
public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {

    stepExecution.incrementVersion();

    final KeyHolder generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

    getJdbcTemplate().update(connection -> {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(getQuery(SAVE_STEP_EXECUTION), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setInt   ( 1, stepExecution.getVersion());
        ps.setString( 2, stepExecution.getStepName());
        ps.setLong  ( 3, stepExecution.getJobExecutionId());
        ps.setDate  ( 4, stepExecution.getStartTime() != null ? new Date(stepExecution.getStartTime().getTime()) : null);
        ps.setDate  ( 5, stepExecution.getEndTime() != null ? new Date(stepExecution.getEndTime().getTime()) : null);
        ps.setString( 6, stepExecution.getStatus().toString());
        ps.setInt   ( 7, stepExecution.getCommitCount());
        ps.setInt   ( 8, stepExecution.getReadCount());
        ps.setInt   ( 9, stepExecution.getFilterCount());
        ps.setInt   (10, stepExecution.getWriteCount());
        ps.setString(11, stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
        ps.setString(12, truncateExitDescription(stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitDescription()));
        ps.setInt   (13, stepExecution.getReadSkipCount());
        ps.setInt   (14, stepExecution.getWriteSkipCount());
        ps.setInt   (15, stepExecution.getProcessSkipCount());
        ps.setInt   (16, stepExecution.getRollbackCount());
        ps.setDate  (17, stepExecution.getLastUpdated() != null ? new Date(stepExecution.getLastUpdated().getTime()) : null);
        return ps;
    }, generatedKeyHolder);

    stepExecution.setId(generatedKeyHolder.getKey().longValue());
}

@Override
public void saveStepExecutions(final Collection<StepExecution> stepExecutions) {
    Assert.notNull(stepExecutions, "Attempt to save a null collection of step executions");
    for (StepExecution stepExecution : stepExecutions) {
        saveStepExecution(stepExecution);
    }
}
```

Change or create copy of JobRepositoryFactoryBean (SqlServerJobRepositoryFactoryBean) with the following changes:

```
@Override
protected JobInstanceDao createJobInstanceDao() throws Exception {
    SqlServerJdbcJobInstanceDao dao = new SqlServerJdbcJobInstanceDao();
    dao.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcOperations);
    dao.setJobIncrementer(incrementerFactory.getIncrementer(databaseType, tablePrefix + "JOB_SEQ"));
    dao.setTablePrefix(tablePrefix);
    dao.afterPropertiesSet();
    return dao;
}

@Override
protected JobExecutionDao createJobExecutionDao() throws Exception {
    SqlServerJdbcJobExecutionDao dao = new SqlServerJdbcJobExecutionDao();
    dao.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcOperations);
    dao.setJobExecutionIncrementer(incrementerFactory.getIncrementer(databaseType, tablePrefix
            + "JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ"));
    dao.setTablePrefix(tablePrefix);
    dao.setClobTypeToUse(determineClobTypeToUse(this.databaseType));
    dao.setExitMessageLength(maxVarCharLength);
    dao.afterPropertiesSet();
    return dao;
}

@Override
protected StepExecutionDao createStepExecutionDao() throws Exception {
    SqlServerJdbcStepExecutionDao dao = new SqlServerJdbcStepExecutionDao();
    dao.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcOperations);
    dao.setStepExecutionIncrementer(incrementerFactory.getIncrementer(databaseType, tablePrefix
            + "STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ"));
    dao.setTablePrefix(tablePrefix);
    dao.setClobTypeToUse(determineClobTypeToUse(this.databaseType));
    dao.setExitMessageLength(maxVarCharLength);
    dao.afterPropertiesSet();
    return dao;
}
```

Create a batch configuration to use new SqlServerBatchConfigurer that uses the new SqlServerJobRepositoryFactoryBean:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SqlServerBatchConfigurer basicBatchConfigurer(BatchProperties properties, DataSource dataSource) {
        return new SqlServerBatchConfigurer(properties, dataSource);
    }

    class SqlServerBatchConfigurer extends BasicBatchConfigurer {

        private final DataSource dataSource;
        private final BatchProperties properties;

        SqlServerBatchConfigurer(final BatchProperties properties, final DataSource dataSource) {
            super(properties, dataSource);
            this.properties = properties;
            this.dataSource = dataSource;
        }

        @Override
        protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
            SqlServerJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new SqlServerJobRepositoryFactoryBean();

            // this is required to avoid deadlocks
            factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ");

            factory.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
            String tablePrefix = this.properties.getTablePrefix();
            if (StringUtils.hasText(tablePrefix)) {
                factory.setTablePrefix(tablePrefix);
            }
            factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        }
    }
}
```